# How to obtain info that file is still open for ftp

Tags: linux, shell, ftp, synology

I use the server (Synology NAS) on which are copied by ftp, video clips from recorders of CCTV system. When file is copied, small script convert it from DAV format to AVI, using the statement below:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.dav" -exec ffmpeg -y -i {} -vcodec copy -movflags +faststart {}.avi \;
```

The problem is that there is a lot of clips transmitted constantly from CCTV recorders to Synology. That is many clips is transmitted from recorders to Synology at the same time. So the statement above will try to convert even clips where transmission is not over yet. How can I exclude such non complete clips from conversion? I can not use "inotify" or "lsof" feature because there is not such facility in Synology Linux (I can not install optware on Synology because of many reasons). I think that it is necessary to know that particular file is still open for writing and exclude it for conwersion. Any idea What to do?

Comment: It may be possible to inspect /proc/PID/fd for the files that your process has opened as explained here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66273.  Another way may be to use the modified date from the `stat -c %y file` command and wait for it to stop changing.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got workaround for my problem. Single video clip is less than 10MB in size. So time of transsmision of sigle file is less than 1 min max. Because of that I add in find command, modification time as argument. It resolve my problem. All problems I have are because of limited functionality of Synology Linux. Se below new command syntax:

```
find ./ -type f -mmin +10 -name "*.dav" -exec ffmpeg -y -i {} -vcodec copy -movflags +faststart {}.avi \;
```

Notice that if file was no modify during last 10 min, that means that transmission procedure ended and in reality of my application (CCTV video clips collecting) it is not necessary to check is the file open or not.